# connected components algorithm in pig

Tags: algorithm, graph, mapreduce, apache-pig

we looked around for a simple algorithm to find connected components in a graph where the diameter is sometimes large (the largest components can sometimes reach 1m).

We found lots of very sophisticated MR algorithms:

- http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.de/2011/04/graph-exploration-with-hadoop-mapreduce.html
- http://blog.piccolboni.info/2010/07/map-reduce-algorithm-for-connected.html
- http://chasebradford.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/mapreduce-implementation-for-union-find/

What's wrong with a very simple algorithm:

- foreach component, generate flatten(nodes_bag) as node, node_with_the_smallest_id as comp_id;
- group by node
- filter nodes with more than one comp_id, and build "update big comp_id to small comp_id" table
- update all nodes with a big comp_id to the corresponding new small comp_id, and mark them as dirty

and continue to the next iteration with these dirty nodes...
what are we missing here?

Comment: How many iterations could this end up taking?

Comment: log(largest_diameter) iterations

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your proposed algorithm quadratic?  Tarjan's connected components algorithm is linear.

Comment: What do you mean by quadratic? IMO The number of iterations would be log(largest_diameter), agree?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the start of your algorithm, where you say "foreach _component_ ...".

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The reason we can't use this very simple algorithm is that it has a bug = the build "update big comp_id to small comp_id" stage could be recursive. E.g, when there are 3 components from the previous iteration:

```
A->{1,2}
B->{2,3}
C->{3,4}
```

The group by and filter would build us this translation table:

```
A->B
B->C
```

And this would cause the number of iterations to be linear(biggest diameter) in some cases = long chains like in this mini example would take a long time to converge.